# Get constant term with `Coefficient` for a non-polynomial

Tags: expression-manipulation

Take a nonlinear equation such as

```
exp = (x + 3)/4 + Exp[x] + 1 + (c + x)
```

Note that this is not a polynomial.  Now, I want to extract the coefficients of this.  A few are easy:

```
Coefficient[exp, x ] (* Correctly gives 5/4*)
Coefficient[exp, Exp[x] ] (* Correctly gives 1*)
```

But how can I extract the coefficient on the constant term?

I can't figure out how to write the "form" for the coefficient function to extract it.  Note that treating it as a polyomial and asking for the 0th order will not work (e.g. `Coefficient[exp, x,0]` is not correct)

Comment: Maybe `Select[exp, FreeQ[x]]`?

Comment: Thanks.  Seems close.  Sadly, my expression is actually a little complicated, and Coefficient is doing some useful work.  I just wrote a small variation of the expression which doesn't seem to be working with your `Select` approach.

Comment: Could you post the more complicated expression?

Comment: `Select[ExpandAll[exp], FreeQ[x]]` probably works for the revised `exp` -- don't know about the 'real' one, however.

Comment: Thanks, simple enough!  Should work for my current problem at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html):

```
exp = (x + 3)/4 + Exp[x] + 1 + (c + x);
CoefficientList[exp, {x, Exp[x]}]
(*  {{7/4 + c, 1}, {5/4, 0}}  *)
```

Whether that is a convenient way depends on what you want to do with it.  Following extracts the parts:

```
{{const, ExpC}, {xC, xExpC}} = %
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it.  Seems strange that you can't put in a constant pattern for the Coefficient function, though.

Comment: @jlperla  I agree.  One can do `Fold[Coefficient[##, 0] &, exp, {x, Exp[x]}]` but it's hardly more convenient.  (Or maybe it is?)

Comment: Yeah, I think yours may be the winner.  If I end up with many more coefficients (doing an undetermined coefficients solution to an ODE) your technique lets me extract from the top corner but also seems to tell me if I missed any terms since they would show up in the constant if I forgot them.

Comment: @jlperla Thanks.  Another idiomatic alternative: `exp /. Thread[Sort[{x, Exp[x]}, MemberQ] -> 0]`.

Answer (score 7):

I usually do something like

```
expr = (x + 3)/4 + Exp[x] + 1 + (c + x);

xCoeff = Coefficient[expr, x];
expCoeff = Coefficient[expr, Exp[x]];
rest = Collect[expr - xCoeff*x - expCoeff*Exp[x], x];

{xCoeff, expCoeff, rest}
```

> ```
> {5/4, 1, 7/4 + c}
> ```