# Getting just the terms independent of a certain variable

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a very long and convoluted expression with many variables and my goal is to get just the terms which are coefficients of $e^{it}$. The variable $t$ never appears outside of exponential terms (only as $e^{ikt}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$), so when I multiply through by $e^{-it}$, the terms I'm looking for are independent of $t$, while every other term has some $t$ dependence in it.

Is there a way to return ***only*** the terms which are independent of $t$ (while being dependent on some other variables)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Coefficient` would work in this case.

```
expr = E^(I Range[5] t). RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {5, 1}] // First
```

> 2 E^(I t) + 6 E^(2 I t) + 5 E^(3 I t) + 10 E^(4 I t) + E^(5 I t)

then

```
Coefficient[expr, E^( I t)]
```

> 2

Answer (score 3):

[This related question gives an answer to my own.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83400/get-constant-term-with-coefficient-for-a-non-polynomial?rq=1) The first comment suggests:

```
Select[expr,FreeQ[t]]
```

This returns the expression given but removes all terms which are dependent on the variable $t$.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [`FourierCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCoefficient). For example:

```
expr = x Exp[I t] + 2 y + 3 z Exp[-I t];
FourierCoefficient[expr, t, 1]
```

> x